# Calling Custom Icons in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I add a custom icon that I created in Wordpress/Woocommerce? My theme has bootstrap and a plugin I am using has icons and they are called like this

```
<i class="glyphicons cup"></i>
```

If I created my own icons (they are icon format) what folder do I place them in and how do I call them as they are above? Lets say the file name is customicon.ico

Comment: I've never seen Bootstrap icons called like that...

Comment: As written we can't know where you are trying to add icons. I also don't see how this is related to WooCommerce at all.

Comment: I am trying to add an icon in a menu in woo commerce. The plugin I have used calls icons as referenced above. Unless the is another way I can get an icon to appear thats all I am looking for? Its for woo commerce thats what I am using

Comment: You should be using an icon font, not an icon file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a function to your functions theme

```
function my_post_type_icon() {
?>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#YOUR_ID .wp-menu-image {
    background: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/YOUR_ICON.png") no-repeat 10px 7px !important;
}
</style>
<?php
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_post_type_icon' );
```

If you want to add  you will need to use the code of your icon and use ::before selector.

hope this helps